# How to mark a specific zone in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Context: We have this thing called "Raise profile" where you spend some credits to make your profile more visible in the search results for the next 24 hours.

We have a highcharts based chart with the number of visits received over the last 7 days. I want to somehow mark the zone between where the profile was raised and see how many visits were in that interval.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jyjz2t9/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 150
  },
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: xAxis,
    offset: 1
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function(){
      return "<b>" + this.y  + "</b>" + " " + this.series.name
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: "vizite",
    color: "#663366",
    states: {
      hover: {
        lineWidthPlus: 0
      }
    },
    data: data
  }]
})
```

Also, the data format can be changed. I'm just stuck at how to mark the zone in the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines. There are jsfiddle examples on the bottom of the page.

The relevant API page is: [xAxis.plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands)

Comment: that seems to be the answer. One question, if I hover over the plotBand, can I get a tooltip saying how many visits are in that interval ?